# Compiling custom kernel with Ubuntu patches

Tags: kernel, patch

I have compiled my own custom kernel but it uses a modified source from github. It doesn't  have any patchset, at least to my knowledge, or any Ubuntu patches like the one required by ureadahead.

Are there patches that they use or a way to create one to apply to the one I used before?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any patches, so I had to create one.

I needed two kernel sources: the one found in the `linux-source` package on Ubuntu and the stable vanilla kernel source that corresponds to the appropriate version of `linux-source` from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/)

Assuming I have extracted all archives to `a`, the vanilla one, and `b`, the Ubuntu one to my Desktop I run the command:

```
diff -Nur /home/mark/Desktop/a/ /home/mark/Desktop/b/ > the-patch.patch
```

`the-patch.patch` is the patch you can apply in any modified kernel sources (like `pf-kernel`) to apply the changes in the stock kernel.